# NReco PDFGenerator issue

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I've been using this tool for about a week, and now, today, it just stopped working.  I've reverted the rest of my code back to the previous state and I keep getting the same error.

All that I'm getting from the Exception that is thrown is:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in NReco.PdfGenerator.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot generate PDF:  (exit code: -1073740791)

From the Windows Event Log:

> Faulting application name: wkhtmltopdf.exe, version: 0.12.2.1, time stamp: 0x54bd0265
>
> Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524f7ce6
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000409
>
> Fault offset: 0x000a7666
>
> Faulting process id: 0xc8c
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d0deb1a8d73b2f
>
> Faulting application path: C:*****\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120.dll
>
> Report Id: e8c8bcf0-4aa4-11e5-826d-acb57d145db6
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

The reason of this error is not in your code: it seems something changed in your environment and wkhtmltopdf.exe stops working because of missed VC++ 2013 runtime libraries (required for latest v.0.12.2.1).

You can download and install them from Windows Downloads: [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

PdfGenerator embeds x86 build of wkhtmltopdf and you may install only x86-version of redistributable package ( vcredist_x86.exe ).

--- update ---

For latest wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 VC++ 2015 runtime libs are needed.

Comment: In my case  Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 was installed but the code was compiled with VS 2015 after Installing  Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015 problem solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're right latest wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 is compiled for VC++ 2015 runtime libs (I've updated an answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. In my case the exit code was slightly different ((exit code: -1073741515)) but the solution was also to install the Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2015, which you find here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: I have already installed vc runtimes but the issue is still appearing.

Comment: @Zeeshanef what wkhtmltopdf version do you use? The latest 0.12.6 may require newer VC++ runtime libs.

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko It is 1.1.15.0. But my issue resolved after restarting my system. Thanks