# NReco pdf generator Error - libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile (exit code: -1073741819)

Tags: c#, html-to-pdf, nreco

We are using **Nrecopdf generator** to generate pdf from html .it fails with the below error:

*libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile (exit code: -1073741819)*

i tried using version: 1.1.10.0 and 1.1.14.0, in both the versions getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Installing Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 or Packages for Visual Studio 2015 (based on your code) both X86 and x64 Version on your machine you can find same question here: [PDFGenerator issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192115/nreco-pdfgenerator-issue).

My Problem solved by installing this packages.